# How do I make use of an irrelevant equality in a proof?

Tags: agda, equality

```
open import Agda.Primitive
import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as Eq
open Eq public
open Eq.≡-Reasoning
```

Suppose I have a dependent pair whose second element is irrelevant:

```
record ∃' {a b} (A : Set a) (B : A → Set b) : Set (a ⊔ b) where
  constructor _,,_
  field
    fst : A
    .snd : B fst

open ∃' public

syntax ∃' A (λ x → B) = ∃'[ x ∈ A ] B
infix 2 ∃'
infixr 4 _,,_
```

Let's say I happen to use it on a subsingleton, such as `_≡_`:

```
module _ (X Y : Set) (f g : X → Y) where
  K : Set
  K = ∃'[ x ∈ X ] f x ≡ g x
```

How can I make use of this equality in a relevant context? For example, how can I prove this?

```
  thm : ∀ (k : K) → f (fst k) ≡ g (fst k)
  thm (x ,, eq) = {!   !}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can turn an irrelevant proof into a relevant one if you assume excluded middle:

```
open import Axiom.ExcludedMiddle
open import Relation.Nullary
open import Data.Empty

postulate
  decide : ∀ {ℓ} → ExcludedMiddle ℓ

lift : ∀ {ℓ} {P : Set ℓ} → .P → P
lift {P = P} irr-p with decide {P = P}
...                | yes p = p
...                | no ¬p = ⊥-elim (⊥-lift (¬p irr-p))
  where
  ⊥-lift : .⊥ → ⊥
  ⊥-lift ()
```

Of course, if you use `lift` on a type with more than one inhabitant, one will be chosen arbitrarily — it won't recover the actual value of `.P`.

Comment: More generally: for any decidable type, you can use [`recompute`](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Nullary.html#1838) to recover a relevant value from an irrelevant one. Assuming EM is but one way to prove a type is decidable.

Answer (score 1):

The [Agda documentation](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.2.1/language/irrelevance.html#what-can-t-be-done-to-irrelevant-arguments) says you can't use an irrelevant value in a relevant context.

Comment: I am aware. Clearly, it would break the substitution property of equality if it was allowed in the general case. However, when the type in question is `_≡_`, there is at most one inhabitant (at least, assuming K), so this is not a concern. If the inference performed by `thm` is not valid, I'd like to see why (e.g. a model of Agda's type theory where it doesn't hold).

Comment: Please include a (brief) summary of the link in case it gets removed / modified.

Comment: @NieDzejkob How should Agda decide whether a type has one inhabitant? Clearly it's undecidable. So would you recommend an *ad hoc* criterion?

Comment: @Trebor You could provide a proof that `(a b : T) -> a == b`. I'm not saying it should be accepted automatically, just that there should be a way to make it work.

Comment: @NieDzejkob Well, that's how Agda's `isProp` works. It is located in the cubical prelude.